# Poisson regression with Fixed Effects for Panel Data

Tags: python, r, sas, fixed, poisson

I'd like to run a Poisson regression with fixed effects for panel data. I found a 'pglm' package in R to do is but it gives an error message saying that:

> class 'pFormula' is deprecated, simply use class 'Formula'

Does anyone know how to make it work?

If not this package, what would be the way to implement this model (either in R or SAS or Python)?

Comment: Maybe `glmer()` in the `lme4` package would be an alternative?

Comment: Thank  you, ekstroem. Does it work for count data?

Comment: Yes with `family=poisson`